c# how to set ToolStripStatusLabel text in a thread safe way
I have a thread that pings various devices, the thread uses events when a ping is completed or times out.
In a form I have a handler that is connected to one of the events from the pinging thread, in the handler is sets the text of the form status bar strip.
Often this causes an exception, which is:
Cross-thread operation not valid: Control `stsStrip` accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Can anyone help, I've searched around for solutions, but unfortunately all the solutions are incomplete in that the examples will not compile because something is missing from the code.

This example of mine is complete. I suggest that you follow the rules laid down there to begin with and then, when you understand exactly what's going on, you can simplify things in particular scenarios.

@jmcilhinney, thank you, I will take a look

There are tons of different questions about "Cross-thread operation not valid", see for example 1 2. And the solution is to send a message to the UI thread to do whatever it is you need to do, for example with Control.Invoke.

If you fail to understand or implement any of the existing solutions you should to show what it is you are doing, what solutions you have tried, and why they do not work.

@jmcilhinney, the problem I'm getting is that in many of the samples there is a call to .Invoke, ToolStripStatusLabel does not have this function.

Any Control can be used for Invoke, as long as it belongs to the same UI thread. So the using the main form would be common. You can also use SynchronizationContext, and .Post, but you need to call .Current on the UI thread, and hand over that object to the background thread for it to work.

That's because ToolStripStatusLabel isn't a control. Look at the error message. It's telling you that the control at issue is stsStrip, which I assume is the StatusStrip that your label is in. That's the logical control to use to access InvokeRequired and Invoke, but you can use any control on the same form, or the form itself. The point is to invoke a method on the thread that owns the control handle. That's going to be the same thread in every case. I believe that I mention that in post #8 of that thread I linked to, which appears to be what you did.

Thank you @jmcilhinney, using your post I implemented:
private void SetStatusBarText(string strText) {
    if (InvokeRequired) {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate {
            SetStatusBarText(strText);
        });
    } else {
        this.lblStsStrip.Text = strText;
    }
}

No more problem.
